# ChrUbuntu (Acer): How to load kernel 3.8.0-16 instead 3.4.0?

Tags: chrome-os, chrome-book, chrubuntu

I have Acer C7 Chromebook with Intel CPU, and I had installed there ChrUbuntu. I had updated (Chr)Ubuntu to 13.04 daily version using dist-upgrade. But I found that I still use google v.3.4.0 linux kernel, not Canonical v.3.8.0.
So how I can change kernel?

I found how to do it on normal computers with GRUB, but it is Chromebook, so there is NO Grub.

Comment: You might be interested in [this article](http://www.chromebook-linux.com/2011/11/compiling-your-custom-kernel-on.html), even though it doesn't answer your question directly. Last points seem interesting.

Comment: Actually I see your answer is [here on superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/583269/chrubuntu-acer-how-to-load-kernel-3-8-0-16-instead-3-4-0). Just so people will follow the link to the answer. Be aware there is a backlight bug when reading the link answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can switch. The Chrubuntu maintainer hasn't really been packaging things. I think it's because the chromebook's bootloader looks for the kernel in a different partition, so I suspect the kernel is directly written (with `dd`?) to a raw partition that the bootloader (BIOS) knows to look for. I don't think this is insurmountable, but there's no current easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I'm not sure how this works out on older models but</s> chrx.org and newer versions of ChrUbuntu are able to use stock distribution or custom kernels on <s>newer</s> Chromebooks¹.

[Quote](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.de/2013_10_01_archive.html) from the ChrUbuntu project blog:

> Since I started ChrUbuntu back in December of 2010, it's always been necessary to utilize the Chrome OS Linux kernel with Ubuntu in order to solve some compatibility issues with the Chromebook architecture. That's changed with the Chromebook Pixel and the newer Haswell-based Chromebooks like the Acer C720 and HP Chromebook 14. Each of these models supports booting from a more traditional PC BIOS mode which makes it simple to use stock Ubuntu kernels on them.

---

1. Except very old models with Intel Pineview ([1](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Support/Pineview), [2](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Hardware_Compatibility)). Sandy/Ivy Bridge models like the Acer C7/PARROT are supported.